# Calculate $\phi$ on spherical coordinates given two spheres

Tags: calculus, integration

I have two spheres

$$x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$$
$$x^2+y^2+(z-2)^2=4$$

I'm trying to integrate this using spherical coordinates, however I'm actually quite confused about the range of values of $\phi$ since in most cases it goes from $0\le\phi\le\pi$, or in other cases I can get it if I'm given a cone.

However how do I calculate it if I'm only given two spheres?

Comment: You are trying to integrate *what*? Do you want the volume of the intersection between $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2\leq 1$ and $x^2+y^2+(z-2)^4\leq 4$? The first sphere is inside the second one.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to integrate the intersection between both spheres

Comment: The sphere with radius $1$ centered at $(0,0,1)$ lies inside the sphere with radius $2$ centered at $(0,0,2)$, hence the intersection is the smallest sphere, with volume $\frac{4\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @AndréEnriqueBrañezQuiroz: You are trying to *calculate the volume of the intersection of the balls by an integral*. What you are integrating is the function that equals $1$ everywhere (or at least inside the intersection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to integrate over the region between the two spheres, you can use $0\le \phi\le \frac{\pi}{2}$ since
the region lies above the xy-plane and touches the xy-plane.

For example, its volume is given by $\displaystyle V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{2\cos\phi}^{4\cos\phi}\rho^2\sin\phi\;d\rho d\phi d\theta=\frac{4}{3}\pi (2^3)-\frac{4}{3}\pi (1^3)$

Answer (score 0):

$(0,0,0)$ is a common point of our spheres and since $(0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1)$ and $(0,0,2)$ placed on the same line, we see that our spheres are tangent.

Also easy to see that the sphere $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2=1$ placed inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+(y-2)^2=4$ and the rest for you.

$V=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}$.